# How to use Vue 3 package with script setup + Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I come across most packages they are written in Options API. What's the best way to determine how to write it with `<script setup>` + Composition API?

For example:

https://github.com/twickstrom/vue-papa-parse#usage

I installed it and attempted:

`import VuePapaParse from 'vue-papa-parse`
`VuePapaParse.parse(file)`

But I get an error:

`TypeError: VuePapaParse.parse is not a function`

Comment: If you check the "issues" section of that Github repo, you'll find https://github.com/twickstrom/vue-papa-parse/issues/8.

Comment: It's always depends on the implementation. Here $papa is available on component instance and not anywhere else, i.e. it's `getCurrentInstance().proxy.$papa`

Answer (score -1):

I think that package can not use in .
Use the Options API only on that component.
It won't be a problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).